# Hide all Divs except last 2. Number of Divs can increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to **hide** all the **Divs** except **Last 2**. Number of Divs can **increase** in my case.

I have searched some topics, so now i became able to hide all except last 1 div.

Here is my Code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/D83ZC/11/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <p> This is Div 1
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p> This is Div 2
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p> This is Div 3
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p> This is Div 4
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p> This is Div 5
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    border:black 1px solid;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('.container').not(':last').hide();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `.slice()` method.

```
$(".container").slice(0, -2).hide();
```

---

This behaves the same as `Array.prototype.slice`, where the second index you provide may be a negative number which counts back from the end.

This will be very fast, and has the benefit of not relying on non-standard selectors included with jQuery (via Sizzle), which means the browser's native selector engine will do the initial DOM selection.

Comment: @Necromancer: Here's a performance comparison: http://jsperf.com/lt-selector-vs-slice

Comment: @user2736012 Nice comparison

Answer (score 4):

You can use the CSS3 selector nth-last-child

```
$('.container:nth-last-child(n+3)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/D83ZC/12/)

This will select all items that match n+3 for n begining from 0, so this is the third, fourth, and so on; begining from the last